# Infinite loading button on Shopify theme

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Today I've a problem with a Shopify theme when I try to put on cart an Item. The button is infinite loading.
I've an JS error in console and I suspect this come from here:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at Product._setCartCountBubble (theme.js?v=14877781539576074710:8609)
    at theme.js?v=14877781539576074710:8434
```

The line 8609 of the file is:

```
this.cartCountBubble.classList.remove(this.classes.hidden);
```

That's right, cartCountBubble is empty in Object:

```
cartCountBubble: null
```

I don't know where it could have come from other than here and I can't put all the code back together to understand....

Comment: This must be overwritten somewhere in the code look for something in the lines of `this.cartCountBubble = <something here>`. It may reference an element with a specific class or id that you don't have on your theme and that's why it still stay as `null` but you need to look through the code to find it.

Comment: I think there is a modification into the header, and somebody removes the element that checked while the AJAX cart script is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue. It was indeed a mistake I have done in the header...

```
<div style="display: none;" id="CartCount" class="site-header__cart-count{% if cart.item_count == 0 %} hide{% endif %} critical-hidden" data-cart-count-bubble>
     <span data-cart-count>{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
     <span class="icon__fallback-text medium-up--hide">
           {{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }}
     </span>
</div>
```

I used to remove the count bubble of the card icon... it was the origin of my problem